# Return an Observable<boolean> instead of Observable<HttpResponse> for HttpClient.post

Tags: angular

How can I return an `Observable<boolean>` in my method instead of the `Observable<HttpClient<AuthResponse>>`?

I have this code:

```
  login(username: string, password: string) {
    const body = {username: username, password: password};
    return this.http.post<AuthResponse>(`${this.baseUrl}`, body, { observe: 'response' })
      .subscribe(response => {
        const user = response.body;
        if (user && user.token) {
          localStorage.setItem(this.localStorageKey, JSON.stringify(user));
          return true;
        }

        localStorage.removeItem(this.localStorageKey);
        return false;
      });
  }
```

Comment: You don't return an observable of *anything* from the method, you return a subscription. But in general, to convert `Observable<S>` to `Observable<T>`, you need to `.map((S) => T)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `map` operator and return the observable.

```
login(username: string, password: string) {
  const body = {username: username, password: password};
  return this.http.post<AuthResponse>(`${this.baseUrl}`, body, { observe: 'response' }).map(response => {
    const user = response.body;
    if (user && user.token) {
       localStorage.setItem(this.localStorageKey, JSON.stringify(user));
      return true;
    }

    localStorage.removeItem(this.localStorageKey);
    return false;
  });
}
```

Comment: Why use `switchMap` and return observables, rather than use `map` and return booleans? There's nothing asynchronous there to observe.